# Temp Table Garbage Collection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I seem to be running into a problem with temp table garbage collection:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SetTestTempTable(@value bit)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TestTempTable
SELECT @value AS Value INTO #TestTempTable

GO

EXEC dbo.SetTestTempTable 1
SELECT * FROM #TestTempTable
```

The above code produces the error

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Invalid object name '#TestTempTable'.
```

I think because #TestTempTable is getting garbage collected when the proc exits.

Is there a way of preventing this? I don't want to have every caller need to explicitly create the temp table before calling the procedure.

UPDATE:
Why am I doing this?

I have the need to store some contextual information (basically a session variable). I was using CONTEXT_INFO for this. SQL Azure doesn't support CONTEXT_INFO, so I'm refactoring accordingly. Essentially, I have a function:

GetMySessionVariableName()

and a procedure

SetMySessionVariableName(value)

Previously, this function and procedure used CONTEXT_INFO internally, and that worked fine. Now, with temp tables, it doesn't...I'm open to suggestions on alternative approaches.

Comment: As it stands it's not possible, given your final constraint. You could select into the temp table and then select from the temp table. We'd all agree that would be pretty silly since you could have just selected the data. So that leads to the next part, *this is clearly not the whole picture*. If you could provide some more information then the help will be much better.

Comment: @p.campbell how will he query the table variable outside of the stored procedure?

Comment: For the updated requirement, what does this session variable do for you exactly? What is it keyed to? How long is it valid? More information is better than less information.

Comment: There a couple of them: 1. User Id, 2. Ability to modify standing system metadata (normally triggers/constraints restrict this), 3. Tenant Name (multi-tenant client name)

Comment: This is a prime example on SO of needing to step back and restate the goals to get a better solution.  Obviously, the goal is to find an effective replacement for CONTEXT_INFO (based on your requirements and how you currently use it) in SQL Azure and a question with a good answer to that would be very valuable.

Comment: A much more valuable response would be something along the lines of "Azure isn't suitable for serious application development. It's just another scenario where Microsoft has decided they need to jump on a bandwagon and releases a half-baked, poorly implemented, minimally supported, so-called solution. Look toward something better thought out and implemented like Amazon RDS." Goodbye Azure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The #temp table is dropped (well, deferred dropped) when the stored procedure goes out of scope. So it is not available to you outside of the scope of the stored procedure. In order to see the contents of #temp after the procedure finishes, you need to create it before you execute the stored procedure, and populate it inside... or perform the select inside the stored procedure.

For the updated requirement, why not just use a permanent table with a key on UserID, and update your stored procedures to take UserID as a parameter? If you already have a Users table you could surely store updated session information in a column or two there. No CONTEXT_INFO or #temp table nonsense required.

Answer (score 0):

There was a solution that I found for this problem but I myself didn't think it is reliable.
It was about having two different connection strings:

1. First to Set Context Info of the Master database with Master Database Connection String
2. Second is your normal Application's Connection String.